# Is there a way to see what status effects do?

Tags: elden-ring

I've just started the game, but I already have a lot of different status effects. I'm talking about these icons under the stamina bar:

[image: status effects]

Is there a way to see in-game what these do? If I remember correctly, [demons-souls](/questions/tagged/demons-souls) remake has a nice help screen where all icons were explained. Is there anything similar in Elden Ring?

I play on PS5 if it makes any difference.

**EDIT**: Of cause I can use wiki, but I would prefer to have some in-game info as well. Demon's Souls remake has this page, but looks like this was just a QoL addition from Bluepoint Games:
[image]

Comment: Check the Wiki, it has all the status icons and a nice description. https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Status+Effects

Answer (score 5):

As of version 1.02, there is no in-game way to read descriptions of the various buffs and debuffs in-game. A wiki will be your best bet for figuring out their effects. You can also attempt to manually track them by being observant when they appear and disappear, but this will not be helpful for all of the icons as some have nothing to do with equipment and items, but rather actions you have performed in-game. Here is a link to the [Status Effect wiki article](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Status+Effects).